# removing entity from database that has already been removed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my application, client has a copy of the persisted entities, stored in a collection so to minimize database transactions. Since its a multi user system, another user might be viewing the same object lets say of a task entity with you. Suppose the second user removes the task from the database while you are viewing the task, and you decide to remove it too. When you try to remove it, I get a StackOverflowError, and of course removal is not executed (since task is allready removed). Is there a way to catch this using database, jpa or hibernate exception? I am using entitymanager obects to remove an entity.

```
public <T> void remove(T entity) throws PersistenceException{
    log.debug("Removing entity of type " + entity.getClass().getName());

    // TODO add exception handling
    EntityManager em = createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(em.merge(entity));
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is an optimistic locking problem. It's not only removal that will be troublesome. There may be two or more people editing the same entity as well (or one will edit an entity, another will remove it, what should be the end result?).

In your case, before removing the entity, you need to first load it in your transaction. If it's not found, someone has already removed it. Otherwise you can remove it safely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for catching the exception; then you may try like below--

```
public <T> void remove(T entity) throws PersistenceException{
log.debug("Removing entity of type " + entity.getClass().getName());
 EntityManager em =null;
 EntityTransaction et=null;
try{
      em = createEntityManager();
      et=em.getTransaction();
   if(!et.isActive()){  // you should have new txn always. else throw expception
     et.begin();
      ....  // your remove logic
    et.commit();
    em.close();
    } else{
       et.setRollbackOnly();
        throw new RunTimeException(..); //optional throw
    }
 }catch(Exception e) {
   et.rollback();
   throw new RunTimeException(...)..; //optional throw
}
```